# Ontology Populating

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, ontology, semantic-web

*Hello everyone*,

because of my lack of experience with ontologies and web semantics, I have a conceptual misunderstanding. When we refer to 'ontology population', do we make clones of the ontology with our concrete data or do we map our concrete data to the ontology? If so, how is it done? My intention is to build a knowledge graph using an ontology (FIBO ontology for the loans domain) and I have also an excel file with loans data. Not every entry in my excel file corresponds to the ontology classes predefined. However, that is not a major problem I suppose. So, to make myself more clear, ***I want to know how do I practically populate the ontology?***
Also, I would like to note that I am using neo4j as a graph database and python as my implementation language, so the process of the population of the ontology would have been done using its libraries.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: might want to check out https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/nsmntx/current/importing-ontologies/.  I think you're dealing with owl ontologies? More detail on the input files you are trying to migrate to Neo4j would be helpful in encouraging replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video could inform your understanding about modelling and imports for graph database design: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXziS-PPIUA

He steps through importing a CSV in to Neo4j and uses python.

The terms ontology and web semantics (OWL) are probably not what you're asking about (being loans/finance domain, rather than web). Further web semantics is not taken very seriously by professionals these days.

"Graph database modelling" is probably a useful area of research to solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer is highly appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @elioraca no worries! an upvote or green tick would be great ^_^

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend you use Apache Jena to populate your ontology with the data source. You can use either Java or Python. The first step begins with extracting triples from the loaded data depending on the RDF schema, which is the basis of triple extraction. The used parser in this step may differ to be compatible with the data source in your case it is the excel file. After extracting triples, an intermediate data model (IDM) is used for mapping from the triple format. IDM could be in any useful format for mapping, like JSON. After mapping, the next step will be loading the individuals from the intermediate data model to the RDF schema that was previously used. Now the RDF schema is updated to contain the individuals too. At this phase, you should review the updated schema to check whether it needs more data, then run the logic reasoner to evaluate and correct the possible problems and inconsistencies. If the Reasoner runs without any error, the RDF schema now contains all the possible individuals and you could use it for visualisation using Neo4j